# A question about semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

When we consider the classification of the group G by semidirect product, we need to consider all the homomorphisms from K to Aut(H), Where G=HK and H$\unlhd$G,H$\bigcap$K=1

But by the  theorem: Suppose G is a group with subgroups H and K such that, (1) H$\unlhd$G (2) H$\bigcap$K=1. Let $\Phi$:K$\to$Aut(H) be the homomorphism defined by mapping k$\in$K to the automorphism of left conjugation by k on H. Then HK$\cong$H$\rtimes_{\Phi}$K.

we can get if G=HK and H$\unlhd$G,H$\bigcap$K=1, then G$\cong$H$\rtimes_{\Phi}$K with the $\Phi$ showed above.Thus it seems if G=HK and H$\unlhd$G,H$\bigcap$K=1, then G is defined only by H and K. In this sense, it seems when we consider the classification of the group G by semidirect product, we don't need to consider other homomorphisms as they are isomorphic to G and G$\cong$H$\rtimes_{\Phi}$K with the $\Phi$ showed above.

Let me show my analysis in an example, in the groups of order 12. Let V$\in Syl_2(G)$ and T$\in Syl_3(G)$. By the Lagrange theorem V$\bigcap$T=1. And we consider the case that V$\cong Z_2\times Z_2$, T$\cong Z_3$ and V$\unlhd$G. By semidirect product we can get G=$A_4$ or $ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$.
Now we apply the theorem, here $A_4$=VT and V$\unlhd$$A_4$,V$\bigcap$T=1, similarly we have $ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$=VT and V$\unlhd$$ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$, V$\bigcap$T=1. Thus apply the theorem to both $ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$ and $A_4$ , we can get $ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$$\cong$V$\rtimes_{\Phi}$T(with the $\Phi$ showed above), and $A_4$$\cong$V$\rtimes_{\Phi}$T, therefore we can get $ Z_2\times Z_2\times Z_3$ is isomorphic to $A_4$.A contradiction.

I know my analysis is wrong, but could you tell me where I made the mistake? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure if I understand exactly what you asking. For any specific group $G$ of this type there is a specific $\Phi:K \to {\rm Aut}(H)$ for which $G \cong H \rtimes_{\Phi} K$. But if you change $\Phi$ then you get a different group $G$. One of the difficulties in carrying out this classification is that different homomorphisms $\Phi$ sometimes give rise to isomorphic groups $G$, so you have to determine when this happens.

Comment: I think the symbol $H\rtimes K$ is misleading - it should be $H\rtimes_{\Phi} K$, as the group so constructed depends on $\Phi$

Comment: @DerekHolt, let me be more specific, to the groups with order n, in order to make the classification we need to find the possible normal subgroup H and subgroup K  with |HK|=n, H$\bigcap$=1 and try to find out all the homomorphisms from K to Aut(H), then by a triple (H,K,$\phi$), we can define a group G with order n. However, by the theorem above, it seems if we have normal subgroup H and subgroup K  with HK=G, then G is determined by H$\rtimes_{\Phi}$K with Φ:K→Aut(H) be the homomorphism defined by mapping k∈K to the automorphism of left conjugation k on H.  it seems all the triples are same

Comment: In the case of $G=HK$ with $H$ normal, $K$ acts on $H$ by conjugation giving you the "missing" homomorphism $\Phi$.

Comment: @Joseph I am still unsure what you are asking. What you write all seems correct, so what is the problem? As I said, any give $G$ of this form detemrines $\Phi$, but different $\Phi$ may result in nonisomorphic groups $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt, I just added an example, where I showed the same analysis from my argument. I hope it can make sense to you. Thank you!

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, you are right, I have edited, thank you, I also added an example to show my question.

Comment: @j.p. do you mean I forgot to add the $\Phi$ to my semidirect symbol?

Comment: @Joseph: No. You wrote "G is defined only by H and K" and "we don't need to consider other homomorphisms", which made me think (probably wrongly) that you had the (wrong) idea that given an inner semi-direct product $G=HK$ that there is only one way how to get an outer semi-direct product at all. But this seems not to be your problem (which I do not understand) with semi-direct products. In your example with $n=12$ you get for $A_4$ a non-trivial homomorphism $Z_3\to Aut(Z_2^2)$, but for $Z_2^2\times Z_3$ the trivial homomorphism.

Comment: @j.p. Thank you, actually in my example I am wondering, why by applying the theorem I showed(Let Φ:K→Aut(H) be the homomorphism defined by mapping k∈K to the automorphism of left conjugation by k on H.) I can get both  Z2×Z2×Z3 and  A4 are isomorphic to V$\rtimes_{\Phi}$T, thus they are isomorphic?

Comment: @Joseph: Why do you think that for both groups $A_4$ and $Z_2^2\times Z_3$ you would get the same homomorphism?

Comment: @j.p. No, I know there are two homomorphism that you said. Actually I just wonder why by using homomorphism from the theorem(i.e the left conjugation) we can still get the semi-direct isomorphism?

Comment: @j.p. I get an idea to explain my question, in the case of ${Z_2}^2\times Z_3$ the left conjugation is actually trivial, while in the case of $A_4$, the left conjugation is the non-trivial one. DO you think it's right?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, as $Z_2^2\times Z_3$ is abelian, conjugation is trivial. In $A_4$ an element of order $3$ never commutes with an element of order $2$, so conjugation is definitely *not* trivial. If you define two semi-direct product with different homomorphisms $K\to Aut(H)$ the resulting semi-direct products *might* be anyway the same, but you cannot expect them to be the same. Here they are not as one group is abelian and the other one isn't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26519/discussion-between-joseph-and-j-p).